# Why do people write html in huge walls of text?

Tags: html

I've seen this a lot lately: **writing html in huge blocks of text that are almost undecipherable**

An example is google classroom,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" dir="ltr"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,width=device-width"/><title>Classroom</title><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/classroom/favicon.png"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" nonce="Ow7v164RuDuF18G2DPJ6ww"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Google+Sans:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet" nonce="Ow7v164RuDuF18G2DPJ6ww"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=924620788"><script nonce="Ow7v164RuDuF18G2DPJ6ww">;this.gbar_={CONFIG:[[[0,"www.gstatic.com","og.qtm.en_US.3gGou_DPQGQ.O","com","en","265",0,[4,2,".40.40.40.40.40.40.","","1300102,3700209,3700321,3700800,3700817,3700831,3700879","369134291","0"],null,"FMSGYJ6zOMO1zwK6pZk4",null,0,"og.qtm.PoHfeJrvkfI.L.W.O","AA2YrTuZTrLZ4SHM1gfcCFFxdZIZ-5oj0Q","AA2YrTtlkmhqEx9CuPzOCQfBhsNqzgdKAw","",2,1,200,"USA",null,null,"265","265",1],null,[1,0.1000000014901161,2,1],[1,0.001000000047497451,1]
```

Why do they write like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt anyone writes it like that. HTML code does not need to be indented and browsers and other applications ignore the indentation. But for readability's sake we do use indentation.

You could paste this code into your editor and have a plugin that formats it the right way or you could try an online HTML formatter.

The code is probably written with indentations like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,width=device-width"/>
      <title>Classroom</title>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/classroom/favicon.png">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" nonce="Ow7v164RuDuF18G2DPJ6ww">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Google+Sans:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet" nonce="Ow7v164RuDuF18G2DPJ6ww">
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
      <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=924620788">
      <script nonce="Ow7v164RuDuF18G2DPJ6ww">;this.gbar_={CONFIG:[[[0,"www.gstatic.com","og.qtm.en_US.3gGou_DPQGQ.O","com","en","265",0,[4,2,".40.40.40.40.40.40.","","1300102,3700209,3700321,3700800,3700817,3700831,3700879","369134291","0"],null,"FMSGYJ6zOMO1zwK6pZk4",null,0,"og.qtm.PoHfeJrvkfI.L.W.O","AA2YrTuZTrLZ4SHM1gfcCFFxdZIZ-5oj0Q","AA2YrTtlkmhqEx9CuPzOCQfBhsNqzgdKAw","",2,1,200,"USA",null,null,"265","265",1],null,[1,0.1000000014901161,2,1],[1,0.001000000047497451,1]
```

Edit: To answer the comment. The HTML interperter does ignore whitespace for instanse when we have enters between words as in this image:

[image]

The browsers ignores those whitespaces and renders those words next to each other.[image]

I made a small snippet to demonstrate this aswell.

```html
<body>
    <p>word
    word
    word</p>
</body>
```

Comment: It definitely does not ignore indentations. I wrote a very basic website and it did not ignore them when I pressed ctrl+u

Comment: The source file does keep the indentation but the HTML interperter ignores it when rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This is for performance and file size, since the computer does not have to process the technically unnecessary newline characters. However, a few things to keep in mind:

The effect is very small

People write code normally then use a program to remove the newlines

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh. What program is it?

Comment: There is not one program for it @hmmaybe. Different companies use different programs and might even have written their own programs for it. If you Google "HTML Minifier" you can find plenty of resources.